# pyqt5 draggable rectangles on picture

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am very new to pyqt5 and trying to figure out how to replicate the following idea.

1. Load an image.
2. Draw MOVEABLE rectangle(s) on top.

   -- by Moveable, I mean rectangles that I can move via click and drag after initial placement.  Like if I dropped it on the top right of picture, I can later move it to middle of the picture.

   -- rectangles(s) multiple is very important. hopefully I can add/remove them dynamically too.
3. ideally show a text associated with the rectangle, like a, b, c... that is editable. (nice to have)

The following picture from LabelImg show cases the idea very well.

[image]

At this point in time, I have been able to load a picture and display it via QLabels and converting to PixMap.  The self.ui, is the typical syntax for loading a UI from QT Designer.

```
class ImageLoader(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        
        self.ui = Ui_Form() # from QT Designer
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.frame_image_label.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.ui.frame_image_label.setAcceptDrops(True)
       
        #.... other stuff not quite relevant #####
        
        # a special draggable Label (see below)
        # The following does NOT work.  (And I want to be able to make multiple labels on key-press...)
        self.special_label = DragLabel('hii', self.ui.frame_image_label)

    def go_to_image(self):
        '''Load the image from a video into the base QLabel to show'''
        self.current_frame_number, img = self.video_folder.get_frame(self.current_frame_number)
        if img is None:
            return
        
        img = self.video_folder.resize_image(image = img)
        
        pixmap = convertCvImage2QtImage(img)
        if pixmap.isNull():
            return
        self.ui.frame_image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

I have also created a custom DragLabel

```
class DragLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, button_text, parent):
        super().__init__(button_text, parent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            mimeData = QMimeData()
            drag = QDrag(self)
            drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
            
            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
```

The current issues:

1. The special_label does show up in my UI.  But it doesn't move when I drag it.
2. It is not constrained to my self.ui.frame_image_label area

In general, the reason Im not using the LabelImg, which is very nice, is because I'm trying to label a VIDEO, and am mainly use this as "correction", ie finding where the Area of Interest was incorrectly identified and then hand-correcting them.  Hence the need to able to move my selections.  Also, I am trying to embed "play/pause", slider selection of frames for ease of use.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Musicamante has the correct idea in that we should swap to the Graphics View Framework and use views and scenes.
QLabels with pictures is not the correct idea.

Comment: While this can theoretically be achieved with QWidgets, the common suggestion is to switch to the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html). It might have a steeper learning curve, but, in the long run, it's the more effective solution: simply put, sooner or later you'll probably want to add some basic transformation (most usually, scaling/zoom), and doing that with standard widgets is terribly complex unless you're very experienced - and if you're *that* experienced, you'd use the graphics view from the beginning.

Comment: yea.  it looks like that is actually what I need.  at least in terms of the click to add a box type of thing.  thanks!  happy to mark yo you as correct answer if you want to shift your comment to an answer